# How to create the HTML table in the VF Email Template?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

I am creating a VF email template. In it, I have to create an HTML table as showne below. How we can create that ?

[image]
I wrote the follwoing code but it does not give me the required output what Ido I need to change ?

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Legal Case" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case">   
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >        
        <style>   
            table, tr, td {
               border: 1px solid black;
               font-family: arial, sans-serif;
               text-align: left;
               font-size: 15px;
            }
        </style>      

        <p><b>Case Info</b></p>
        <table border="1px" >
            <tr>
                <td><b>First Name</b></td><td>{!relatedTo.firstName}</td><td><b>Last Name</b></td><td>{!relatedTo.lastName}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Description</b></td><td>{!relatedTo.Description}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

The above code generates the following output:

[image]

Comment: That output looks more or less what you need, no? **Description** is also appearing in the table, is that the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following line

```
<td><b>Description</b></td><td>{!relatedTo.Description}</td>
```

to this

```
<td><b>Description</b></td><td colspan='3'>{!relatedTo.Description}</td>
```

and if you need to give more height to the **description** column, then add `style` to it. Something like (add height in **px** as per your need)

```
<td><b>Description</b></td><td colspan='3' style='height:60px'>{!relatedTo.Description}</td>
```

Comment: Thnx works fine  !!

Comment: @user4567570: help others locating the answer by selecting the answer, **if** it solved your problem. Thanks. :)